Testing router.push with vitest and testing-library for vue 3 project
im new in testing components and im trying to test a simple login function. Everything works and tests as it should expect for the push function. This is my login function, which executes whenever you click on the Login button:
function login(){
    let data = qs.stringify({
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    })
    wrongPassword.value = false
    console.log(data)
    axios.post('/api/users/login',data,{withCredentials:true}).then(async response=>{
        if(response.status==200){
            store.register_notifications()
            await router.push({name:'MyEvents'})            
        }else{
            console.log(response)
        }
    }).catch(err=>{
        if(err && err.response && err.response.status==400){
            store.toggleMessage = 'Error: ' + err.response.data.message
            wrongPassword.value = true
        }else{
            store.toggleMessage = 'Error: ' + err.response.data.message
            console.log(err)
        }
    })
}

Here it is my Router: '@/router/router.js' if needed:
import LogIn from "../pages/LogIn.vue";
import Profile from "../pages/Profile.vue";
import Notifications from "@/pages/Notifications.vue";
import MyEvents from "@/pages/MyEvents.vue";
import EventDetail from "@/pages/EventDetail.vue";
import Settings from "@/pages/Settings.vue";

import { appStore } from "@/stores/store";
import axios from "@/stores/axios";
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/login",
        name: "Login",
        component: LogIn,
    },
    {
        path: "/profile",
        name: "Profile",
        component: Profile,
    },
    {
        path: "/myevents",
        name: "MyEvents",
        component: MyEvents,
        meta: {
            transition: ""  
        }
    },
    {
        path: "/notifications",
        name: "Notifications",
        component: Notifications,
    },
    {
        path: "/:catchAll(.*)",
        name: 'any',
        redirect: {name:'MyEvents'},
    },
    {
        path: "/details/:id",
        name: "EventDetail",
        component: EventDetail,
        meta: { 
            transition: "slide-right", 
        },
        beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
            const store = appStore();
            store.getevent(to.params.id);
            next();
        }
    },
    {
        path:"/settings",
        name:"Settings",
        component: Settings,
    },
];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if (savedPosition) {
        if (from.name === 'EventDetail'){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(savedPosition)
            }, 300)
            })    
        }else{
            return savedPosition
        }
        }else{
        if (from.name === 'EventDetail'){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve({ top:0 })
            }, 300)
            })    
        }else{
            return { top:0 }  
        }
        }
    }
})

router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
const store = appStore();
store.routeBefore = from.name 
  if (store.profileEditing){
     store.profileSave = false
     store.to = to.name
     next(false)
  }else {
    if (to.name !== 'Login') {
      const logged = await store.auth();
      if (logged) {
        store.getnotifications()
        if (to.name === 'EventDetail' && from.name !== 'Notifications') {
          to.meta.transition = 'slide-right';
        } else if (to.name === 'MyEvents' && from.name === 'EventDetail' && store.eventDetailExitTransition) {
          to.meta.transition = 'slide-out-right';
          store.eventDetailExitTransition = false;
        } else{
          to.meta.transition = '';
        }
        next();
      }else {
          next({
          name: 'Login',
          replace: true
          });
      }
    }else if(from.name === 'Notifications' && to.name === 'EventDetail'){
        next({
            name: 'MyEvents',
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
  }
});


export default router;

First try
The first thing I tried was creating a router from scratch, as I saw in tutorials or as suggested by ChatGPT (although it didn't make much sense to me since the router was already created in my application). The test was as follows:
import { fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/vue';
import { describe, it, expect, vi } from 'vitest';
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from 'pinia';
import { renderWithPlugins } from '@/utils/render.js';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory} from 'vue-router';
import axios from '@/stores/axios.js';
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import qs from 'qs';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import LogIn from '@/pages/LogIn.vue';
import MyEvents from '@/pages/MyEvents.vue';
import Profile from '@/pages/Profile.vue';
import Notifications from '@/pages/Notifications.vue';
import EventDetail from '@/pages/EventDetail.vue';
import Settings from '@/pages/Settings.vue';



const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: App, name: 'Home' },
    { path: '/login', component: LogIn, name: 'Login' },
    { path: '/profile', component: Profile, name: 'Profile' },
    { path: '/myevents', component: MyEvents, name: 'MyEvents' },
    { path: '/details/:id', component: EventDetail, name: 'EventDetail' },
    { path: '/notifications', component: Notifications, name: 'Notifications' },
    { path: '/settings', component: Settings, name: 'Settings' },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

describe('LogIn', () => {
    let mock
    beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(createPinia());
        vi.resetAllMocks();
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
      });
    afterEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks()            
    });
   it('submits the form with the correct data', async () => {
        mock.onPost('/api/users/login').reply(200);

        const { getByPlaceholderText, getByRole } = render(LogIn);
        const emailInput = getByPlaceholderText('Email');
        const passwordInput = getByPlaceholderText('Contraseña');
        const loginButton = getByRole('button', { class: 'log-in1' });

        await fireEvent.update(emailInput, 'whatever@gmail.com');
        await fireEvent.update(passwordInput, 'esteban');
        await fireEvent.click(loginButton);
        await waitFor(() => {
            // expect(mock.history.post.length).toBe(1);
            const request = mock.history.post[0];
            expect(request.url).toBe('/api/users/login');
            expect(request.data).toBe(qs.stringify({
                email: 'whatever@gmail.com',
                password: 'esteban',
            }));
            expect(router.currentRoute.value.path).toBe('/myevents');
        });
    });
});

In this case, the test was not valid because instead of changing to the '/myevents' route, it changes to the '/' route.
Second try
The second thing I tried, after looking at a forum, was mocking the router instead of creating a new router from scratch:
const mockRoutePush = vi.fn()
vi.mock('vue-router', async () => {
  return {
    RouterView: {},
    useRouter: () => {
      return {
        push: mockRoutePush
      }
    }
  }
})
describe('LogIn', () => {
    let mock
    beforeEach(() => {
        setActivePinia(createPinia());
        vi.resetAllMocks();
        mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
      });
    afterEach(() => {
        vi.clearAllMocks()            
    });
    it('submits the form with the correct data', async () => {
        mock.onPost('/api/users/login').reply(200);

        const { getByPlaceholderText, getByRole } = render(LogIn);
        const emailInput = getByPlaceholderText('Email');
        const passwordInput = getByPlaceholderText('Contraseña');
        const loginButton = getByRole('button', { class: 'log-in1' });

        await fireEvent.update(emailInput, 'whatever@gmail.com');
        await fireEvent.update(passwordInput, 'esteban');
        await fireEvent.click(loginButton);
        await waitFor(() => {
            const request = mock.history.post[0];
            expect(request.url).toBe('/api/users/login');
            expect(request.data).toBe(qs.stringify({
                email: 'whatever@gmail.com',
                password: 'esteban',
            }));
        });
        // await router.isReady();
        expect(mockRoutePush).toHaveBeenCalled()
        expect(mockRoutePush).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
            expect.objectContaining({ name: 'MyEvents' })
        )    
    });

});

And find this error:
Error: \[vitest\] No "createRouter" export is defined on the "vue-router" mock. Did you forget to return it from "vi.mock"?
If you need to partially mock a module, you can use "importOriginal" helper inside:

vi.mock("vue-router", async (importOriginal) =\> {
const actual = await importOriginal()
return {
...actual,
// your mocked methods
}
})

❯ src/router/router.js:61:16
59| \];
60|
61| const router = createRouter({
|                ^
62|     history: createWebHistory(),
63|     routes,
❯ src/stores/store.js:3:31

After finding this error i tried to fix it by doing:  (as a chat gpt suggestion):
const mockRoutePush = vi.fn();

vi.mock('vue-router', async (importOriginal) => {
  const actual = await importOriginal();
  return {
    ...actual,
    createRouter: actual.createRouter,
    useRouter: () => ({
      push: mockRoutePush,
    }),
    RouterView: {},
  };
});

That lead to this final error where i got stuck for hours:
\` FAIL  src/tests/LogIn.test.js \> LogIn \> submits the form with the correct data
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called at least once
❯ src/tests/LogIn.test.js:149:31
147|         });
148|         // await router.isReady();
149|         expect(mockRoutePush).toHaveBeenCalled()
|                               ^
150|         expect(mockRoutePush).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
151|             expect.objectContaining({ name: 'MyEvents' })

\`

I would love to hear about your suggestions to solve this problem!!!

It's not shown that router.push comes from useRouter. It's reasonable to expect this but any way, needs to be confirmed. If you write a unit test, it's a mistake to use unmocked router. Any units except the tested one are supposed to be mocked. In your case a router is tied to fake browser's location and will result in test cross-contamination. The problem is that you used code that needed createRouter at all, means that it was imported while it probably shouldn't in unit test. It may be unnecessary to mock the entire vue-router, but at least use memory router instead of createWebHistory
